# Laravel - get count in tree structure, where count in parent is sum of counts from children

Tags: php, laravel, count, tree, relationships

I'm struggling with this issue for some time, can't really find the solution, so I'm hoping for some help.

I have two related models, `ModelOne` that is also related to itself and can have infinite number of children, grandchildren etc., and is related to `ModelTwo`.

```
class ModelOne extends Model
{
    ...

    public function model_two()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ModelTwo::class, 'foreign_key');
    }

    //recursively get all children, grandchildren etc.
    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany(ModelOne::class, 'foreign_key')->with('children');
    }

    public function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo(ModelOne::class, 'foreign_key');
    }
}

class ModelTwo extends Model
{
    ...

    public function model_one()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ModelOne::class, 'foreign_key');
    }   
}
```

In my get function from `ModelOne` I have:

```
public function get($id = null) {
    return is_null($id) ?
        ModelOne::withCount('model_two')->get() :
        ModelOne::withCount('model_two')->where('id', $id)->first();
}
```

and that gives me nice one-dimensional array of objects (or one object), with count form related `ModelTwo`, which I need, but with individual count for every related object.

The thing I need is, for every `ModelOne` object in return array who has children, grandchildren etc., to count in that object be the sum of counts from all its children, grandchildren etc. 
So, for example, if I have one object of `ModelOne` with id=2, parent_id=1 and count of 3, and another object with id=3, parent_id=1 and count of 2, then for object with id=1, that is parent to previous two, count would be 5. This logic continues up in the tree for all nodes.

```
[
  {
    "id":1
    "parent_id":"NULL",
    "model_two_count":5
  },
  {
    "id":2
    "parent_id":1,
    "model_two_count":3
  },
  {
    "id":3
    "parent_id":1,
    "model_two_count":2
 }

 ...

]
```

Answer (score 4):

So, I figured out solution, and here it is for all of you who may be struggling with the same problem.

First, in my `ModelOne` I have added `withCount('model_two')`, so that I immediatly have relation count from `ModelTwo`. I have also added a property `$return_count` that will hold the sum of counts from all children-grandchildren-etc.

```
class ModelOne extends Model
{

    private $return_count = 0;

    ...

    public function model_two()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ModelTwo::class, 'foreign_key');
    }

    //recursively get all children, grandchildren etc.
    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany(ModelOne::class, 'foreign_key')->withCount('model_two')->with('children');
    }

    public function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo(ModelOne::class, 'foreign_key');
    }
}
```

Then, I have added two helper functions, one that recursively gets all the children-grandchildren-etc. for given parent id, or gives back all the records from table:

```
public function get_recursive($parentId = null){
    return is_null($parentId) ?
        ModelOne::with('children')->get() :
        ModelOne::where('id', $parentId)->with('children')->first();
}
```

Output from this function like this:

```
[
  {
    "id":1
    "parent_id":"NULL",
    "model_two_count":0.
    "children": [
        {
            "id":2
            "parent_id":1,
            "model_two_count":3
        },
        {
            "id":3
            "parent_id":1,
            "model_two_count":2
         }
      ]
   }

 ...

]
```

This example is for two-dimensional nesting, but it can go *infinitely* deep.
Return object created in this function becomes input parameter in the second function. The second function is actually doing the recursive summation of counts from all the children-grandchildren-etc. for the given parent object. Property `model_two_count` can be accessed because it gets created when `withCount('model_two')` was called. Also, property `children` gets created when `with('children')` was called.

```
private function count_sum($parentChildren) {
    foreach ($parentChildren->children as $child) {
        $this->return_count += $child->model_two_count;
        $this->count_sum($child);
    }
    return $this->return_count;
}
```

At the end I call my get function:

```
public function get($id = null) {
    if(is_null($id = null)) {
        $data = ModelOne::withCount('model_two')->get();                 
        return $data->map(function ($i) {               

            //get all children-grandchildren-etc. for specfic object with id = $i->id
            $children = $this->get_recursive($i->id);

             //if object with id = $i->id have children then model_two_count is sum of all model_two_count from all children-grandchildren-etc.                    
             if (!empty(array_filter((array)$children->children))) {
                $i->model_two_count = $this->count_sum($children);
                //reset the return_count variable for next iteration. If this is not done, then sum from previous object will be added to the next object count
                $this->return_count = 0;
            } 
            return $i;
        });
    } else {
        $data = ModelOne::withCount('model_two')->where('id', $id)->get();                 
        return $data->map(function ($i) {
            $children = $this->get_recursive($i->id);
            if (!empty(array_filter((array)$children->children))) {
                $i->model_two_count = $this->count_sum($children);                         
                $this->return_count = 0;
             } 
             return $i;
         })->first();
     }
 }
```

And that will get you desired nice output:

```
[
  {
    "id":1
    "parent_id":"NULL",
    "model_two_count":5
  },
  {
    "id":2
    "parent_id":1,
    "model_two_count":3
  },
  {
    "id":3
    "parent_id":1,
    "model_two_count":2
 }

 ...

]
```